# Create loading spinner in react-native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, node.js, react-native

I have created a loading spinner that is being used across my components in my React project. I am now creating a react-native version of this application, and want to re-create this loading spinner in react-native.

I am struggling to get this to work as a react-native screen. I have attempted to use `Animated` from `react-native` but have had no luck. I would like the exact same animation.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative
}

.load {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
}

.loader {
  border:0;
  margin:0;
  width:40%;
  height:40%;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation:spin 2s ease infinite
 }

.load1 {
  background:#19A68C;
  animation-delay:-1.5s
}
 
.load2 {
  background:#F63D3A;
  animation-delay:-1s
}

.load3 {
  background:#FDA543;
  animation-delay:-0.5s
}

.load4 {
  background:#193B48
}

@keyframes spin {
  0%,100%{transform:translate(0)}
  25%{transform:translate(160%)}
  50%{transform:translate(160%, 160%)}
  75%{transform:translate(0, 160%)}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="load">
    <div class="loader load1"></div>
    <div class="loader load2"></div>
    <div class="loader load3"></div>
    <div class="loader load4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Reanimated as animation library but you should re-write your animations(delay,spin etc.) in react-native-reanimated while keeping your other styles(background or margin).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ActivityIndicator` from React-Native

```js
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

/......

<ActivityIndicator size={50} color={"white"} />

/......
```

Answer (score 0):

js style does't work in react-native.
you can achieve your desire loading spinner by getting json from **Lottie Animation** then you can render it using `lottie-react-native` package.

I'm made my custom loading spinner from Lottie Animation and using it as component like this

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import myAnimation from '..//..//assets/animations/loadingSpinner.json';
import colouriseLottie from '../CustomLoadingSpinner';
import styles from './style';
import AppColor from '../../constants/Colors';

const LoadingSpinner = ({containerStyle}) => {
const {APP_DEFAULT_COLOR} = AppColor();

const colorizedSource = useMemo(
() =>
  colouriseLottie(myAnimation, {
    'layers.0.shapes.0.it.0.it.10.c.k': APP_DEFAULT_COLOR,
    'layers.0.shapes.0.it.1.it.1.c.k': '#fff',
  }),
 [],
);

return (
 <View style={containerStyle}>
  <View style={[styles.spinnerView]}>
    <LottieView
      speed={0.5}
      style={{width: 90, height: 90}}
      source={colorizedSource}
      autoPlay
      loop
    />
  </View>
 </View>
 );
 };

 export default LoadingSpinner;
```

note: ignore the coulriseLottie because I dynamically change the color of my app that reflect change in custom loading.

Hopefully it will you.